# Is there a way to render the wireframe without the triangulation?

Tags: rendering, wireframe

The Wireframe node gives out an output in which the faces are triangulated. Is there any way in which I can use the wireframe which I see in the viewport. ie. before the triangulation of the mesh occurs in the render engine? And in case I am using a Subdivision Surface Modifier, is it possible to use just the original wireframe that I am workinng with? The image below will definitely clear  things up if you did not understand what I have typed above.

[image]

And I know that this might be possible using the wireframe modifier on a duplicated copy of the object and stuff. But I don't want that. I want to be able to use this wireframe in the shader editor itself as some kind of mask.

Comment: You can get what you want if you do a render through View > Viewport Render Image?

Answer (score 1):

(On my phone right now, will post pictures later if needed)

It should be quite easy to do with Grease Pencil (GP):

1. Make a Collection to which you can assign any object you want to show a wireframe on, or skip to next step if you want all the objects of your scene anyway.
2. Shift A > Add a Grease Pencil Line Art collection or scene. It will create an empty GP object with a Line Art GP modifier targeting your scene or collection.
3. In that Line Art GP modifier, make sure the right collection/scene it targeted. And enable at least "Edge Marks":
   [image].
4. Select all the mesh objects you want wireframes on, Tab into Edit mode, select all edges, hold down Alt and set the Grease Pencil Edge setting in the sidebar to 1.

From there you can edit the material, add modifiers and change the scene GP settings to customize the looks of your GP.

[Good to read](https://blenderartists.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-render-wireframe-lines-only-with-materials/1455164/7?u=l0lock)